# Expresión Regular para validar un número de 9 cifras no empiece con 9 y no contenga dos ceros consecutivos en sus 8 dígitos restantes

Tags: javascript, php, html5, regex, input

Necesito una expresión regular que acepte 9 dígitos y cumpla lo siguiente:

- Primer dígito → 0-8 (o sea que no empiece con 9)
- Entre 2do. Al 8vo. Dígito → != 00 (no que acepte los dos ceros juntos)

He intentado `/^[0-8]{1}[0-9]$/` pero no funciona.

Comment: Que has tratado de hacer?

Comment: /^[0-8]{1}[0-9]$/   por momento eso y no se si este bien.

Comment: @MxMxxWC con el objetivo de que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, eso que acabas de comentar debías adjuntarlo a tu publicación. Las preguntas que no muestran nada de código y no muestran un intento del usuario por resolverla son muy mal vistas, por ello los votos negativos.

Comment: Te he respondido porque he visto que has intentado resolverlo. Recuerda adjuntar tu progreso en futuras preguntas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usa algo como:

```
^[0-8](?!.*00)\d{8}$
```

Donde:

- `^[0-8]` asegura que la cadena no empiece con 9.
- `(?!.*00)` asegura que no existan dos ceros consecutivos
- `\d{8}$` asegura que termina en 8 dígitos (más el primero 9).

Puedes probarla en este link https://regex101.com/r/MyBxPQ/1

Comment: Lo he revisado y entendido, muchas gracias. Tenes razón, sobre el código debo agregarlo en la publicación. Gracias master.